# Aligning HTML element using margin 0 auto

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the middle button which called "center" to the center of the page. 
I tried to use margin 0 auto with no success. Anyone know whats I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=container>
    <div id="left">
      <input type="button" value="left">
    </div>

    <div id="center">
      <input type="button" value="center">
    </div>

    <div id="right">
      <input type="button" value="right">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the css

```
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#left, #center, #right {
  display: inline-block;
}

#center {
  background-color: red;
  width: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center it, if there is no parent container, as you said in the comments, give `#center` `display:block` then `margin: 0 auto;` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there is NO parent container? 
How I centering the middle button to the center using margin 0 auto?

Answer (score 5):

- add `text-align:center` for the `#container`
- add `display:inline-block` to `#center` so that it can be centered with parent `text-align` property
- add `float:left` for the `left` button and `float:right` for the `right` button

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
#center {
  display: inline-block;
}
#center {
  background-color: red;
  width: 65px;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id="left">
    <input type="button" value="left">
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <input type="button" value="center">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <input type="button" value="right">
  </div>
</div>
```